# When does a system of homogeneous quadratic equations have integer solutions?

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

I learned that in general, solving systems of quadratic Diophantine equations is a difficult problem. But I wonder if there are special (and non-trivial) types of systems that are easier to handle.

For instance, I am interested in the following scenario:

- There are $n$ unknowns and $(n-1)$ *homogeneous* quadratic
  Diophantine equations in the system. So each equation can be written
  as a quadratic form $x^TAx=0$ for a symmetric matrix $A$.
- The matrix
  $A$ is zero-diagonal (and thus indefinite). The non-zero entries of $A$ are
  only $1$ or $-1$.
- Each $A$ has a small rank.

I am not sure if the above situation is too specific. My main question is whether there are cases when the problem of solving a system of homogeneous quadratic Diophantine equations is easier. And I will appreciate any suggestion for references related to the questions.

Comment: This paper by Lagarias may be relevant https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611209

Comment: Thank you for the reference!

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046t281f3046_system_of_equations